Unable to send influxdb data to SQL server using influx script in Chronograf
I'm using below system,

Ubuntu 20.04 VPS in Linode
Mosquitto MQTT
Telegrapf
InfluxDB v1.8.10

SQL Server database with sql auth credentials in company own azure account.
I have few IOT devices that send data related to a machine output.
The data is going from the device to InfluxDB using mqtt.
Link,
IOT -> MQTT Mosquitto -> Telegrapf -> Influxdb
I have setup Grafana for visualization. But for my company systems, I need to concat records and send them to SQL server periodically. I have used influx and tested it with mysql using Chronograf.
But when I try to connect with sql server, driver is not supported.
failed to initialize execute state: sql driver sqlserver not supported"
How to solve this?
Influx script documentation does shoe that sql server is supported for "sql.to()" with sqlserver as the driver.
import "sql"

from(bucket: "xDB/autogen")
|> range(start: -1w)
|> filter(fn: (r) =>
r["_measurement"] == "xMold")
|> rename(columns: {_value:"Status", deviceId:"DeviceID", _time:"Time"})
|> drop(columns: ["_field","_measurement","host","topic","_start","_stop"])
|> sql.to( driverName: "sqlserver", dataSourceName: "sqlserver://usrName:usrPasswrd@comp-db.database.windows.net:1433?database=PROD_DB", table: "MachineStatus",
)

This is the script I use.
